# Apply style in a table to specific columns within the th and td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and I want to be able to assign specific styles within CSS to certain columns in the table: -

```
<table border="1">

<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
<th>Header 3</th>
<th>Header 4</th>
<th>Header 5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
<td>row 1, cell 3</td>
<td>row 1, cell 4</td>
<td>row 1, cell 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
<td>row 2, cell 3</td>
<td>row 2, cell 4</td>
<td>row 2, cell 5</td>
</tr>

</table>​
```

I want to be able to give the first 2 th only the style of `text-align:left;` and the remaining `th = text-align:center;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard and direct solution :

```
th {
   text-align:center;       
}
tr th:nth-child(1), tr th:nth-child(2) {
   text-align:left;   
}​
```

The advantage of this notation is that it's easy to change it to apply for example to the fourth and sixth `th` instead of the first two.

Note that this supposes [the availability of CSS3 in the browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

If you want to be compatible with IE8, you might do it easily in javascript :

```
var ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th'); // replace document by your table if necessary    
for (var i=2; i<ths.length; i++) ths[i].style.textAlign="center";
```

or with jQuery :

```
​$('th').each(function(){
    if ($(this).index()>=2) $(this).css('text-align', 'center');
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
    th:first-child, th:first-child + th{
        text-align:left;
        }
th + th + th{
        text-align:center;
        }
```

live demo http://tinkerbin.com/B5Zi88Pp

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 way

```
th {
text-align:center;
}
th:nth-child(0), th:nth-child(1) { text-align:left; }​
```

CSS2 Way

```
th{
text-align:center;
}
th:first-child, th:first-child + th{
text-align:left;
}
```