# Assign styles to certain elements within a table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apply style in a table to specific columns within the th and td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638587/apply-style-in-a-table-to-specific-columns-within-the-th-and-td)

I have a table and I need to be able to assign different styles to different columns, I need: -

1. The first two columns in the table header (header1 and header 2 to be given text-align:left; then all the remaining headers within the table header to be given text-align:center;
2. Similar thing with the table rows, the first two for all rows in the table to be given text-align:left; then the rest of the tds given text-align:center;

So basically the first two columns throughout the table will be left, then remaining be centered??

`

```
<tr>

<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
<th>Header 3</th>
<th>Header 4</th>
<th>Header 5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
<td>row 1, cell 3</td>
<td>row 1, cell 4</td>
<td>row 1, cell 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
<td>row 2, cell 3</td>
<td>row 2, cell 4</td>
<td>row 2, cell 5</td>

</tr>
```

​

Comment: What's the difference with your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638587/apply-style-in-a-table-to-specific-columns-within-the-th-and-td) ? Just that you add the row requirement ?

Comment: yes, couldnt get it working when I tried similar to the rows, the first row kept showing the styles for the th

Comment: You can duplicate my precedent answer and simply replace th by td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table has a class `mytable`:

```
.mytable td, .mytable th {
    text-align: center;
}
.mytable td:first-child, .mytable td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left;
}
.mytable th:first-child, .mytable th:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left;
}
```

This can be written more compactly as:

```
.mytable td, .mytable th {
    text-align: center;
}
.mytable td:nth-child(-n+2) {
    text-align: left;
}
.mytable th:nth-child(-n+2) {
    text-align: left;
}
```